# Delay sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have the following code in an `AnswerObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer` in my Rails app. After an answer is created, an email is sent out to users watching the question.

```
  def after_create(answer)
    answer.question.watchers.each do |user|
    Notifier.answer_updated(answer, user).deliver
  end
```

Notifier inherits from ActionMailer `class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base` and has the method

```
 def answer_updated(answer, user)
    @answer = answer
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Your question has been answered")
  end
```

I'm now trying to use SideKiq to move it to a background process. I have redis installed and running and I started sidekiq successfully with `bundle exec sidekiq`.

According to this blogpost http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2013/01/using-sidekiq-to-send-emails-asynchronously, SideKiq has built in support for ActionMailer

```
The method that you will likely use the most is .delay. Calling .delay from an Action Mailer will result in the email being added to the DelayedMailer queue for processing.
```

Therefore, I replaced "deliver" method with 'delay" in the observer that calls the action mailer method answer_updated, like this

```
  def after_create(answer)
    answer.question.watchers.each do |user|
    Notifier.answer_updated(answer, user).delay
  end
```

But now I'm getting this error

```
undefined method `delay' for #<Mail::Message:0x007fee0c9af1d0>
```

I haven't done anything else to configure SideKiq. Can you explain what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to do this is :

```
Notifier.delay.answer_updated(answer, user)
```

See the examples in the file [Here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/extensions/action_mailer.rb)

Comment: or if Tomoko can answer as well, really dumb question, but do I need to do all the other stuff like adding a worker, etc. if all I want to do is use Sidekiq for emails?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It didn't work out for me. There is no `delay` method for `mailer`. Take a look here:

```
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.2.0"
>> Rails::VERSION::STRING
=> "4.2.1"

>> mailer.methods.include?(:delay)
=> false
>> mailer.send_email(mailable, recipient).methods.include?(:deliver_later)
=> true
```

So, if you use Rails > 4.2 use this:

```
Notifier.answer_updated(answer, user).deliver_later
```